# Angular Controller pass data to other controller when page changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controller

Hi I have a Java script file that controls all the controllers. I also have two html page that link one to another when the form is submitted, I need to pass a value to the other controller when the submit button is pressed.

I am able to log the value if I don't direct to another page, but once I direct to the other page, value becomes 'undefined'

here is my two angular controller

```
app.controller('createworkshopController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

    //get bunch of stuff

    $scope.submitWorkshop = function() {    

      $http({method:'POST', data:$scope.result, url: 'url for post method'})
          .success(function(data) {
              $rootScope.ID = data.value;
              console.log($rootScope.ID); //this log return the value
          });
      };
});
```

But when I redirect to the other page the value become undefined
here is the controller for second page

```
app.controller('showworkshopController', function($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

    console.log($rootScope.ID); //this becomes undefined

    $http.get('some_url?Id=' + $rootScope.ID)
    .success(function(data) {
        //do bunch of stuff
    });

    //do bunch of stuff
});
```

my first page html have a submit button written like this

```
    <a href="second-page.html" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitWorkshop()">Submit</a>
```

Comment: I think you create function on second controller, and call it on button click and print value on console log. If this is returning value means your second controller console.log is getting executed before first controller success get executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your app will reinitialise on page refresh/redirect.

You need to build this as a one page app and not do the redirect, or store the value in cookies or local storage before the redirect, and the retrieve on loading the second page.

Basically angular is really meant for building applications, not as an add in to standard web forms.

Comment: I understand single page application would work perfectly, but since time restraint, we are unable to do this. Therefore, how can i store this value as cookies?

Comment: I'd probably use local storage for this. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html Be aware that values will persist between sessions when using this so you might want to clear the values on the first page if they exist

Comment: can I use the angular $cookie getter and setter to achieve the same result?